# Where can I find/edit <div> elements in Joomla 3.10?

Tags: joomla-3.x

Looking to simply add some text to a  element which appears on the homepage - this would take me ten seconds in HTML but I can't find where it's located in the Joomla control panel. I've looked in the template file, in all of the articles, and all of the extensions -> modules.

I'm a Joomla newbie so any help is appreciated - looking to simply try and update a website for a friend. I'm going crazy. Any help or advice would be amazing - thank you! I'm on Joomla 3.10.11.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the site or the HTML snippet of what you are trying to change? The CSS class could potentially tell us whether it is native Joomla or an extension.

Comment: Hiya - I'm trying to edit the text "OUR SERVICES" in this piece of code: https://pastebin.com/raw/B1tsVY3L

I have checked and "top-long-2" doesn't appear anywhere, however "top-long" appears under the module manager. I'm really at my wits' end...

Thanks for replying!

Comment: I can't help from that snippet - what template are you using? I can maybe look at the demo.  Are you able to share the live URL? You can use a URL shortener so you question is not linked back to the website.

Comment: I haven't a Joomlart sub any more but I'm guessing the template uses the T4 page builder? Have you a component or menu item called T4 page builder or similar? If so, you should be able to select the home page and edit the 'block'?

Comment: Thank you for looking! Unfortunately there is nothing called T4 page builder in either the menu or components. The component list is: AcyMailing, Akeeba Backup, CKEditor, Convert Forms, JCE Editor, JMedia, K2, OSMap Free, Post-installation Messages, RC Team, Tags and Web Links. Could any of these be the culprit?

Comment: If you have access to the DB via PHPMyadmin you can use the search tab to find the text/html - I tend to use this as a last resort if I can't find something through the  normal channels. Use % before and after your search term and make sure all tables are selected. Post back if you get stuck.

Comment: After a bit more digging I've just realised your template is not Joomlart, they do have a template called Brisk,  is the the template you have? https://demo.energizethemes.com/brisk

Comment: That's the one! Sorry, I should've specified. I don't have access to the DB unfortunately, but I can ask for the login credentials if that would help. Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I'm running a bit blind now - I'm not familiar with Energize themes. Can you go to Menu > Main Menu, choose the home page and post back the Menu item type.

Comment: The menu item type says "featured articles" - but when I go to "Content -> Articles -> Featured Articles" nothing is there. This is just baffling. Please don't apologize, I appreciate all the help!

Comment: In the menu item...click through the tabs, there may be an option to add a Page header/Title.

Comment: Do you see anything like this? https://imgur.com/a/aarNhD7

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but unfortunately the menu item type only allows me to select the list of components above, or articles. I've been able to edit some things on the homepage, for instance the banner at the top of the page that says "Welcome to Companyname" was found under a module - editing the text in the WYSIWYG editor helped me there. I'm on Joomla 3.10.11 so my screen looks a bit different to yours, but I have a 'page display' tab which sort of looks similar. It just allows me to set the title tag for the webpage, I don't think it actually influences any on-site text sadly. :/

Comment: What is the menu item type? That can give a hint as to where the content is coming from.

Comment: The menu item type says 'Featured Articles', but when I go to Content -> Articles -> Featured Articles, there is nothing there in that category. Very confusing...

Comment: That sounds like a component. Add a new menu item and  look at the options you can select in the 'type' dropdown https://imgur.com/a/3344XM3 Grab a screenshot if you can.

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/G7e7fs9.png These are the only ones I have available :/ (there's also one below it called 'web links' which didn't fit on the screenshot)

Comment: Click K2 to expand it - what are the options?

Comment: "Categories", "Item", "Item edit form", "Latest items from (one or more) users or categories", "Tag", "User page (blog)". That's it :)

Comment: Can you check 'Infozone' and 'newsfeed'

Comment: Infozone only has one expanded category, also called 'infozone' - and newsfeed has 'Login', 'Newsfeed', 'Register'. Both of these (I think) are added by a third-party company which provides news articles for the website automatically.

Comment: I'm running out of ideas - it's a difficult one running blind.

Comment: No worries - thank you so much for taking the time to look at the site and come up with ideas! I really appreciate it. I'll pass that email along to my friend who runs the site :)

Comment: I'll post back if i have any more ideas.

Comment: I've found where the "Our Services" text is located - under Extensions -> Templates -> Styles -> Template name, there are a bunch of tabs and it happens to appear under the "Theme Settings" tab. Unfortunately I don't think there is the option to add any <p> text underneath it, which has sort of rendered this whole effort pointless - but I guess that's the mystery solved?

Thank you so much for your help btw. Really appreciate you taking the time.